# URL with http not working

Tags: mac, firewall, http, https

I have problem with my mac. no url is working with http url and if I use https then it's working fine.

I saw this error in each browser ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I think this might be a virus because before 1-2 hour everything was fine. So please let me know if any one faced the same issue and have solution. Is there any firewall issue?

[image]

Comment: What URL please add screenshots

Comment: What firewall are you running? Did you write a rule blocking outgoing connections to port 80? Does the sysadmin for your network have such a rule installed on your network's firewall? Did you install some security software that blocks insecure HTTP connections? Are you configured to use an HTTP proxy of some sort?

Comment: Might be there is a software who blocked the http connection but right now I don't have idea. There is no sysadmin like this is my personal broadband connection. There might be some software issue because last day I was downloading some video on my mac book but I clicked on wrong download button which downloaded a package of softwares. and I clicked to install those.

Comment: @Saurabh It sounds like you accidentally installed some kind of malware on your Mac and it's hijacking your HTTP connections. Rather than approaching this as a networking problem, you should probably go figure out how to rid your Mac of whatever malware you installed.

Comment: I have the same problem on a 2021 MacBook Pro running Monterey. After a few days of using the computer, I'm unable to connect via http (https works fine), e.g., this fails with a timeout: `curl -v -o /dev/null http://www.google.com`. If I restart the computer, I can access http again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your computer can not make a successful communication to the remote site on port 80.  The problem is probably not DNS related (in as much as you can reach the site on port 443, and the error does not imply a resolution failure) That is all that can be ascertained from the information you have provided.

The problem could be -
Your computer has a virus or firewall blocking the connection.
Your provider (or another provider upstream to them) are blocking connections on port 80
The website is not actually running on port 80.

The most likely would seem to be maintenance or issue on the remote website, or a provider failing in trying to implement a transparent proxy - but these are just guesses.    It could be a virus.

If you try connect with another computer/phone/tablet on your LAN and the problem exists the problem is not with your computer.  If it only exists on your computer, then you have narrowed the scope down.

Comment: this is just the problem on mac laptop right now, on mobile and other window laptop there is no problem.

Comment: even I am not able to make connection with my router. I tried to open my router 192.168.1.1 and there is same problem while I am to make connection through telnet. So this is just the problem with http request only. 
Is there any way to figure out what is the cause of behind this.

Answer (score 0):

See if there is any pf rule added to your Mac and flush all rules.

To List:

```
sudo pfctl -sr
```

To Flush:

```
sudo pfctl -F rules
```

A cheat sheet for pfctl: http://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/